# stylus как реализовать цикл?

Tags: css, stylus

Имеется объект с названиями классов и путем к иконке.

```
currentProject = {'current-project': '../../sprites/123.png',
                  'composition-project': '../../sprites/123.png',
                  'room': '../../sprites/123.png',
                  'terms': '../../sprites/123.png',
                  'documents': '../../sprites/123.png',
                  'command': '../../sprites/123.png',
                  'contact': '../../sprites/123.png'}
```

Как получить результат:

```
&__current-project: 
   background-image: url('../../sprites/123.png')
&__room 
   background-image: url('../../sprites/123.png')
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел более красивое и правильное решение

```
currentProject = {'current-project': '../../sprites/1.png',
              'composition-project': '../../sprites/2.png',
              'room': '../../sprites/3.png',
              'terms': '../../sprites/4.png',
              'documents': '../../sprites/5.png',
              'command': '../../sprites/6.png',
              'contact': '../../sprites/7.png'}

class                 
  for k, v in currentProject
    &__{k}
      background-image v
```

Answer (score 4):

С объектам в stylus работать нельзя, если вы сами заполняете объект, то можно сделать два массива и функцию.

Переменная `selectors` - массив селекторов/классов.
Переменная `sprites` - массив url спрайтов.
Переменная `arrLength` - длина массива она должна быть одинакова для массивов `selectors` и `sprites` и не забываем, что счет начинается с нуля.
В цикле вызываем функцию `generate`, которая возвращает код для каждого элемента массива `selectors` и `sprites`.

Проверить код можно [Stylus Compiler](http://www.beautifyconverter.com/stylus-compiler.php) вставив в левое поле, нажав кнопку "Compile stylus" и в правом окне появится css.

**Stylus код**

```stylus
selectors = current-project,
            composition-project,
            room,
            terms,
            documents,
            command,
            contact

sprites = '../../sprites/1.png',
          '../../sprites/2.png',
          '../../sprites/3.png',
          '../../sprites/4.png',
          '../../sprites/5.png',
          '../../sprites/6.png',
          '../../sprites/7.png'

arrLength = 6

generate(selector, sprite)
    &__{selector}
        background-image url(sprite)

.class
    for num in 0..arrLength
        generate(selectors[num], sprites[num])
```

**Скомпилированный stylus**

```css
.class__current-project {
    background-image: url("../../sprites/1.png");
}

.class__composition-project {
    background-image: url("../../sprites/2.png");
}

.class__room {
    background-image: url("../../sprites/3.png");
}

.class__terms {
    background-image: url("../../sprites/4.png");
}

.class__documents {
    background-image: url("../../sprites/5.png");
}

.class__command {
    background-image: url("../../sprites/6.png");
}

.class__contact {
    background-image: url("../../sprites/7.png");
}
```

Comment: Прошу прощения что не по теме, но как добавить блок "Выполнить код" ?

Comment: @CodeStealer над полем ответа есть иконки и там слева седьмая иконка, документ с <> внутри.

Comment: Спасибо, нашел.

Comment: посмотрите мое решение

Comment: Только вот зачем нужна кнопка "выполнить код", если код невыполнимый?